# how to change sizeof(std::string)

Tags: c++, sizeof, allocation, stdstring

I save my table data in a file with a certain pattern. I will do it with x86 and read it with same pattern. It is correct.

But if a change compiler to x64 i can't read the data from file because std::string allocation size is changing.

in x86 build:

```
printf("string size: %d\n", sizeof(std::string)); // output is "string size: 28"
```

in x64 build:

```
printf("string size: %d\n", sizeof(std::string)); // output is "string size: 40"
```

When compile mode is x64, I can't read the correct data from file due to sizeof variable changing.

Is there any way to change default size of string? if i set it 28 in both compile mode. It is enought for me.

Notes

I am not using sizeof as length i use it for verify data struct

```
typedef struct _USER_TABLE
{
    uint32_t ID;        
    string name;
    uint16_t age;
}



    DWORD dwNum;
    size_t i, j, iDataTypeCount = 0;
    ReadFile(hFile, &iDataTypeCount, 4, &dwNum, NULL);

    std::vector<int> offsets;
    if (iDataTypeCount > 0)
    {
        m_DataTypes.insert(m_DataTypes.begin(), iDataTypeCount, DT_NONE);
        ReadFile(hFile, &(m_DataTypes[0]), sizeof(DATA_TYPE) * iDataTypeCount, &dwNum, NULL);

        if (FALSE == MakeOffsetTable(offsets))
        {
            __ASSERT(0, "can't make offset table");
            return FALSE;
        }
        size_t iSize = offsets[iDataTypeCount];

        if (sizeof(Type) != iSize || DT_DWORD != m_DataTypes[0])
        {
            m_DataTypes.clear();
            printf("Data Type is mismatch or size is incorrect\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I use sizeof(_USER_TABLE) to verify and sizeof the sturct is changing depends on compile mode. Because string's size changing

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: The problem is not with "changing size of std::string". The problem is that your "certain pattern" that you "save your table data" into a file is platform dependent. Change your "certain pattern".

Comment: sizeof is compile time operator. It can't be changed

Comment: Are you aware that `sizeof(std::string)` is not the size of the characters *in* the string, but instead the size of some pointers to the data?

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(std::string)` to save data?  The number of characters in a `std::string` is not `sizeof(std::string)`, it is the `size()` member function.

Comment: The way you save/load from file is probably broken, if it depends on `sizeof(string)`. You shouldn't be writing the string object itself as binary, but rather its `.data()`.

Comment: `sizeof` gives you the size of the `std::string` object. It does *not* give you the length of the string.

Comment: This sounds like you are making the mistake of attempting to save a non-POD type to a "binary" file by doing the `reinterpret_cast<char *>` or similar coding practice.  If you are, your entire approach is broken.

Comment: BTW if the string length is below a certain size (often 15 characters) then the actual characters will be in the footprint of the string object. This is the so-called "small string optimization". But if you go above that size then the footprint of the string just contains some pointers that are meaningless after your program restarts. That is another reason why your approach is broken (in addition to the different size on different platforms, as you have already found).

Comment: @ArthurTacca -- small string optimization is a reason why storing the bits of the string object could appear to work. Sometimes.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you made some wrong assumptions and instead of correcting them you try to fix something that cannot be fixed. Please tell us about what you actually want to achieve so we can tell you how to fix that ("fixing" the sizeof a string cannot be the solution)

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes exactly, that's why they pointed it out: it sounds like so far they have always used small strings, so they are in for a nasty surprise when they use longer strings, even if they use precisely the same platform.

Comment: If you're saving a `std::string` into a file as if it's a binary thing you can just dump in, then later revivify, you're in for a wild surprise. A mammoth frozen ten thousand years ago won't get up and walk around after being thawed, and neither will your strings when you slam them back into raw memory. **The correct way to serialize a string is to write the string data to a file, not the `std::string` object recast as a series of bytes.**

Comment: @OP -- You should be aware that your "solution" could never work, since `sizeof` is a *compile-time* value.  If you had a thousand characters in the string, did you expect `sizeof()` to be 1000?  Also, if you did save your data to a file using `sizeof`, and the amount of data was say 40 bytes, did you look at the file you saved in a file viewer?  Do you see anything looking like the string data you saved?  I bet you don't see any of your string data in the file.  So given that, how would a program reading the file magically change the strange data you would see back into the original data?

Comment: A `std::string` object internally holds a pointer to the string data. Saving the object won't save the data pointed to by that pointer (it'll just save the value of the pointer - which is useless). You want to serialize the object and save the actual string characters it represents.

Comment: CSV is nicer for table data, portable across all languages, apps, CPUs, memory models.  It has just 4 rules: comma separates cells, cr-lf separates rows, double quote cells with comma, cr, lf in them, double double quotes in cell data.

Comment: My usual trick is to store strings Pascal-style. Write the length of the `string` to the stream as an integer of known size and endian, then write the `string`'s data. The reader reads out the agreed-upon number of bytes for the length, adjusts the bytes to the native endian if required, and then reads length characters from the stream.

Comment: i added more details

Comment: If you have certain restrictions on your data you could use a `char []` with fixed size. If not you will need some proper serialization to handle `std::string`

Comment: @seukaiwokeo The `ReadFile` is a Windows OS function, and it just reads raw bytes.  So you need to take a step back and layout how you want your data to look when saved to a file.  Then save your data with that layout.  Then you have to write code that can read the data and populate an instance of  `_USER_TABLE`.  One thing you cannot do is what you are doing now, plain and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the size of the `std::string` class. Nor would changing the size of `std::string` or even knowing that size be useful in storing data in a file because `std::string` is not trivially copyable.

You need to do proper serialisation. One simple approach is to store the content of buffer that `std::string` manages, and to rely on null terminator to determine the length of the written data.

---

P.S. `_USER_TABLE`, `__ASSERT`: These identifiers are reserved to the language implementation. You should use another name for the class, and the assertion assuming you've defined it yourself.

Comment: Be careful relying on a NUL terminator since `std::string` can contain NUL in its payload.

Comment: Better to save the string's `size()` value first, then save the actual characters from the string's buffer.  Then later, you can read the `size()` value first and `resize()` the string, then read the characters into the string's buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A good plan but a bit more fiddly, as you have to be careful about the platform's enddianness and `sizeof(size_t)`.